# ESS and EC2 error "R process has died"

Tags: emacs, amazon-ec2, ess

I am attempting to use ESS with EC2. I start an instance in the EC2 console and then ssh into the instance.

```
M-x shell
cd ~/.ec2
ssh -i zmjones.pem root@ec2-23-22-122-35.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Then I start ESS with

```
M-x ess-remote
```

Where I select `r`. However when I attempt to interact with the process I get an error "R process has died." However I can manually enter commands into the shell by pasting commands from my script into the shell.

Comment: This looks like a bug in ess-remote. Is the exact message "Process R has died"?

Comment: Yes that is it exactly. That is a major bummer if true. It seems to work for other people with EC2 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is not correctly associated with the buffer. Try <kbd>C-c C-z</kbd> or <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd>  to associate the current buffer with the process.

If you still experience this problem, would be good to report on ess bug tracker at github or ess-help.